# I messed up setting up a ufw firewall on Ubuntu and can no longer log in to my server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ssh, firewall

Alright, so I'm not great (or even good) with servers, but have recently been put in charge of the task of setting them up.  I have an application sitting on a VPS, here are the specs that may matter for this question...

Ubuntu 10.04
Nginx
ufw

So I was setting up my first firewall and was using UFW.  I accidentally only opened up ports 80 and 443 (I was confused about setting up an SSL cert (also a new task)) and got logged out of the server.  My ssh is set to try port 22 and so when I try to ssh in, it won't let me, I get this error --

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

So I tried to ssh in on one of the open ports by running this command --

```
ssh deployer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p443
```

and received this error --

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 443: Connection refused
```

The same thing happened for trying port 80.

What do I do? I already have a live and very active application on this server. I need to be able to login and reopen port 22 for ssh or switch ssh over to another port.

Side note: sftp did not work either.

Comment: If it's a VPS you can contact the hosting company or use your client account to run commands on the server.

Comment: I was able to add the rule with vfw through my hosting provider to open port 22! Thank you! You saved me from a heart attack :) feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) VPS providers have a shell integrated in the control panel of the customer, so even if you have the `sshd` off you can still run commands on the server.

If not you can still also contact the hosting company and they can run commands on any of the virtual devices they are hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Because your ssh server is running only on port 22 you will not be able to connect to it through port 80 (usually used for http) or port 443 (usually used for https). So there is nothing you can do from remote :(

Comment: so am I totally screwed? are there work arounds? can I have into my own server?

Comment: It depends. If your provider offers access to the console of the machine you can log in there and fix the config. If you could hack into your machine depends on how you installed it and which applications are running, e.g. for public facing servers there should better no way to hack into them, otherwise other people will do it too and you will be screwed again.

Comment: As mentioned above, your VPS provider probably offers a web-based command line interface that you can use to access to your VPS, through their web site.

Answer (score 0):

If somehow you could upload and execute a file in your application, then to get a shell on the server is only a matter of uploading a [reverse-shell](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet). Some web applications allow the admins (I suppose you're an admin of the web application) to upload this kind of files (.php, .perl, etc.). Maybe is the case of your application. If you can't upload a file, then you probably are screwed.

Note that this isn't a good security practice. The application shouldn't allow you to upload and execute code, because if somehow an admin account is compromised, then the whole server may be compromised.